# List.add overwrites previus items in list VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list

Hi I have a little problem with a list of custom objects i wrote. When I use the list.add(xxx) method it doesn't simply append the xxx object to my list, but it turns each items to xxx and I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the declaration of my custom class:

```
Public Class User

Private Shared n As String
Public Shared Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return n
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        n = value
    End Set
End Property
Sub New(ByVal name As String)
    User.Name = name
End Sub


End Class
```

And here's where I call the list.add method

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub subname
        Dim temp As New User
        Dim data As New List(Of User)
        For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
            data.Add(New User(item))
        Next
    End Sub
End Sub
```

P.S. Yes, I've already read some posts about people having the same problem but did not understand how to apply their solution to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `Shared` property and private member. A `Shared` member is shared among all instances of the class. If you set it in one instance it will be the same for all instances.

```
Private Shared n As String
Public Shared Property Name() As String
  ...
End Property
```

Remove the keyword `Shared` and it should work as expected.

```
Private n As String
Public Property Name() As String
  ...
End Property
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I solved my stupid problem by turning the `User.Name = name` method in `Sub New` into `n = name`